# Android animation on layout

Tags: android, android-animation

I would like to apply an animation on a layout.

This animation should display half layout and the whole layout after 200/300 milliseconds. The images below, tries to explain what I've just said. On the left there is the start of the animation, with the half layout displayed and on the right the final result. The animation should be like opening a page of a book, or something that could remember this.

I've searched for Diagonal transition, but I did not find something useful for me.

Any suggestion to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a clip drawable resource that actually clips a "triangle" of your main view. Then manipulate it to show or hide the triangle progressively. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip

Or you can hardcode paint the triangle you want to hide, check this
https://gist.github.com/Sefford/1be809708ca2fb64353a